# Will StreamWriter.Flush() also call FileStream.Flush()?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, filestream, flush

I have a StreamWriter which underlying stream is a `FileStream`. Will the following code guarantee that the `FileStream` also flushes its buffer into the actual file on the file system, or do I need to explicitly call `Flush()` on the `FileStream`?

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("blabla", FileMode.Append)) {
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
        sw.WriteLine("Hello, I want to be flushed.");
        sw.Flush(); //I need this to also flush onto the file, not just to the FileStream
    }
}
```

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx), "*Flushing the stream will not flush its underlying encoder unless you explicitly call Flush or Close*", but I do not know if a FileStream can be considered an "underlying encoder".

Also, if I don't specify FileOptions.WriteThrough, am I guaranteed that the OS will eventually write the flushed line onto the disk even if the program crashes before the two streams have been closed (assuming for example no `using {}` blocks, only a call to `Flush()`)?

In my scenario I need to leave the stream open (for logging) so I cannot use `using {}` blocks, but I would like to make sure data will always be written to the disk even if the program crashes. I can afford to lose data if there is a power shutdown and the OS has not flushed onto the disk, but otherwise I need the OS to eventually flush even if I never properly call `Close()` on the stream.

Comment: Why you didn't try it yourself?

Comment: I am interested to know whether the behavior is guaranteed and we can rely on it, not whether it works most of the time.

Comment: yes it will flush underlying stream. Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying stream.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, calling `Flush` on `StreamWriter` will cause the underlying stream to be `Flush`ed. The 4.5 version calls a private `Flush(bool,bool)` function, which ends with:

```
if (flushStream)
{
    this.stream.Flush();
}
```

Where `flushStream` is the first parameter, `this.stream` is the stream that the `StreamWriter` was constructed on, and the call in `Flush()` is `Flush(true,true)`.

---

(Older parts of answer - I was being very roundabout in answering. Moved most relevant part of answer to top)

It's not explicitly spelled out in the documentation anywhere I can find it, but any stream class that is constructed by passing it another stream should be assumed to "take ownership" of that stream (unless it's specifically called out otherwise).

That is, once you've constructed the `StreamWriter` using `fs`, you shouldn't perform any direct actions on `fs` yourself.

---

The part you quoted from MSDN relates to the later sentences:

> This allows the encoder to keep its state (partial characters) so that it can encode the next block of characters correctly. This scenario affects UTF8 and UTF7 where certain characters can only be encoded after the encoder receives the adjacent character or characters.

That is, you may have passed data to `Write` such that you've given it some Unicode surrogates, but not a complete character. `Flush` will not write those surrogates to the stream. So long as you're always passing well formed (complete) strings to `Write`, you do not need to concern yourself about this.

---

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. What about the second part of the question? About the guarantee that the OS will actually write the Flush at some point in time even if the Stream is never closed properly and FileOptions.WriteThrough is NOT specified in the FileStream constructor?

Comment: @ErwinMayer - I'm not sure I understand the question. If you **absolutely**, **definitely**, *must* ensure that this data hits the disk, then you almost certainly will need to specify `WriteThrough` - but you'll also need a machine with a disk enclosure with battery backup, etc. Otherwise, I think there will always be a small risk window. I don't know how long this risk window is, and it's likely OS (and possibly OS config, driver, etc) dependent - so not well defined within .NET framework.

Comment: True, in my case as long as the instructions to write data to the disk is submitted to the OS I am fine. I don't mind if the OS does not immediately write onto the disk. I just want to make sure the OS will write flushed data even though the program aborted and streams were not properly closed.

Answer (score 4):

Streams disposal is guaranteed if used with **using block**!

With a chain of streams,closing the outermost stream(at the head of the chain) *`i.e StreamWriter in your case`* closes the whole lot *`i.e FileStream`*

Flush method forces internal buffer to be written immediately.Flush is automatically called when stream is `closed`,so you never need to do the following

`s.Flush();s.Close();`

So,the moment the most topmost stream is closed it flushes and then closes it underlying streams who also flush there content.

**For example** consider this chain

```
FileStream->GZipStream->StreamWriter
```

So,the moment you close the StreamWriter

`StreamWriter` flushes and closes.It also closes undelying `GZipStream`

`GzipStream` flushes and closes.It also closes underlying `FileStream`

FileStream `flushes` and `closes`

Comment: Thanks, I know that closing the StreamWriter closes the FileStream, but the first part of the question relates to whether Flush() is also cascading.
The second part of the question relates to whether, in case the FileStream has NOT been disposed before crashing (e.g. no use of using blocks), but Flush() has been called, whether the OS will still eventually write its internal buffer to the physical disk (provided there is no OS crash or power shutdown of course).

Comment: @ErwinMayer as i said,`flush` is automatically called when the stream is closed or is buffer is filled..The moment the most topmost stream is closed it flushes and then closes it underlying streams who also flush there streams..

Comment: @ErwinMayer tht would be a diff scenario..cuz u can always avoid it by using `using`

Comment: You're adding a lot of information about what happens when the stream is *`Close`d*, but the OP is asking about what happens when *they* call `Flush`. They don't *want* to `Close` the stream (at this time).

Comment: Thanks Damien :). By the way @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It it is not always possible to use "using", in my case hundreds of streamwriters need to be open at the same time in a loop so it cannot be expressed using brackets AFAIK.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hmmm...i never tried 2 understand the question itself..:P